# How do I delay animation ,upto the point where user has loaded the element

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors

look at this page
https://codewithnick.github.io/#about_me

the animation loads on page load
I want the animation the load when the user scrolls down to this section of the page
how do I implement this.
here are my codes

```
@keyframes fill{
  from{
    width: 0%;
  }
  
}

.progress{   
    
    animation: 3s fill ease-out 0.5s;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be add a class to the element that has the animation **when** the user scrolls down.

```
on window scroll {
if (scroll pos > x) {
element.addclass("animatedClass");
  }
}
```

If you want the animation to **only happen once the user scrolls past a certain point**, all you need to do is change the scroll event to remove the class as well, as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    element.addClass("animatedClass");
  }
  else {
    element.removeClass("animatedClass");
  }
});
```

Comment: if someone wants future reference                                                                                 here is the code  elements=document.getElementsByClassName("progress");
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >300) {
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        const element = elements[i];
        element.classList.add("animation_load");  
      }
      
    }
    else {
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        const element = elements[i];
        element.classList.remove("animation_load");
      }